# In Chrome how I can see a webpage's time/date info?

Tags: google-chrome, internet-explorer, date-time, timestamp

In IE I can right-click, select Properties and see the page's date (but not time).

I don't see any similar feature in Chrome.  And how about Firefox.

Comment: modern webpages are dynamically built.  the creation and time is almost always the moment you accessed it.

Comment: My question is when you accessed it.  Say you leave a 'puter on over night. Next day you don't remember if you've refreshed a page.  Is the page yesterday's or when's?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a neat trick to do this that always works for me.

When you are on the page that you are interested in, type the following command in the address bar without the inverted commas:

```
"javascript:alert(document.lastModified)"
```

or if you copy and paste this then leave the inverted commas in and remove these just before you press enter. If you copy and paste without the inverted commas, then the 'javascript:' part will not paste.

When the command runs you will get a pop-up something that shown below with the date and time for the page.

[image: Pop-up with the time and date]

I hope that this explanation makes sense and that it helps.

Comment: This is showing current time on all pages where I've tried it.  Subsequent reruns keep updating the timestamp shown with the current time.

Comment: Some sites modify the page when it is rendered making the modified date the current date which is correct. Try this solution on a more static site like w3schools.com to see that it works. An alternate way of getting the author modified date when the page is modified during rendering is to append /sitemap.xml to the URL to get the sitemap and then read the last modified date.

Answer (score 2):

#### And how about Firefox?

Right click on the page and select "View Page Info":

[image]

[image]

Answer (score -1):

To avoid typing:

1. Copy-paste the following to the address bar:

   **avascript:alert(document.lastModified)**
2. Then **manually add "j"** to the beginning. Then press **Enter**.
3. You will see a pop-up window with the date and time when the file was last touched.

Explanation:
javascript:alert(document.lastModified) is the command you need, but if the full "javascript:" is included in the pasted text, then "javascript:" will disappear and the trick does not work (you have to type it back). This way it suffices to manually type just the missing "j".

This works on Chrome, Edge and other browsers.